# Change margin between .control-group rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I want to change the margin between rows.  Here is what I'm starting with:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z2DB/)

The is default is too much. In **bootstrap.css**, I only see the classes `.control-group.warning`, `.control-group.error`, etc, but there is no `.control-group` main style.

How should I change it?

---

### Edit

I found that this changes it:

```css
.control-group {
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use negative margins.  The following does the trick:

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}​
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/A4J3L/)

Also, unless you are doing a major overhaul of the CSS (in which case you should probably be using LESS), it is usually better practice to leave the **bootstrap.css** unedited, and add your overrides in a **styles.css** file.  That way, you could potentially leverage a CDN (e.g., [BootstrapCDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)).

Comment: Yes im overriding classes just like You wrote.